# OpenVPN Configuration with ufw eth0 doesn't exist to add it in before.rules

Tags: networking, server, firewall, openvpn, ufw

in [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I am asked to edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and add:

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

problem is this vps doesn't have `eth0`

```
root@vps:~# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:304657 (304.6 KB)  TX bytes:304657 (304.6 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:104145 (104.1 KB)  TX bytes:3072 (3.0 KB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13233 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13936 errors:0 dropped:1855 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2282467 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:4621340 (4.6 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:17.14.12.9  P-t-P:17.14.12.9  Bcast:17.14.12.9  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I tried

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

and

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o venet0:0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

but always timeouts when pinging from the clients after connecting

P.S. assume 17.14.12.9 is a real public IP and venet0:0 is the interface that has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE`

and `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source X.Y.Z`
where X.Y.Z is the actual IP address assigned to your VPS. (If that doesn't work, try 
venet0:0 )